# How to use the plutus pab statemachine with RemoteWalletConfig for Nami and Yoroi

Tags: nami-wallet, plutus-pab, statemachines

Looking at the demo contract provided in the plutus-apps folder, you can follow the example of the `PayToWallet` endpoint. In this endpoint, `yieldUnbalancedTx` provides the instance with an unbalanced TX. When fetching the status of the instance, you will find the tx in `cicYieldedExportTxs` field. Offcourse the PAB should be configured with this:

```
walletServerConfig:
  tag: RemoteWalletConfig
```

I want to have the same behavior with my statemachine contract. The call to the pab should verify the onchain state and return a transaction so the state of the contract can be changed from a remote wallet like Nami or Yoroi. What's the counterpart for this `yieldUnbalancedTx` function in the statemachine as I believe the `SM.runStep` tries to submit the Tx instead of returning the tx in the instance.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].